# MagicMirror SQL connection gets ENOTFOUND error even with an IP address

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am using MagicMirror project that can be found on the Github. I have added the MMM-MysqlQuery module. And i have added the database config to the config file. but still gets ENOTFOUND error.

project : https://github.com/MichMich/MagicMirror.git

I have set up the code in a raspberry pi 2. and the mysql database is in the pi localhost.when I run the project using pi terminal i get the ENOTFOUND error.

```
config: {
  connection: {
   host: "http://192.168.8.100",
   port: 80,
   user: "root",
   password: "123456789",
   database: "mirror"
}
```

according to understanding this configurations are passed as parameters to the
MMM-MysqlQuery modules'  config.js file. which has the db connection initialization.

```
var mysql = require("mysql");

var con = mysql.createConnection({
 host: process.argv[2],
 port: process.argv[3],
 user: process.argv[4],
 password: process.argv[5],
 database: process.argv[6]

});

con.connect(function(err) {
 if (err) throw err;
 con.query(process.argv[7], function(err, result) {
     if (err) throw err;
     console.log(result);
 });
});
```

And the error i get is like this

```
Whoops! There was an uncaught exception...
{ Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND http://192.168.8.100 
 http://192.168.8.100:80
 at errnoException (dns.js:50:10)
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:92:26)
 --------------------
at Protocol._enqueue (/home/pi/MagicMirror/modules/MMM-MysqlQuery/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
at Protocol.handshake (/home/pi/MagicMirror/modules/MMM-MysqlQuery/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
at Connection.connect (/home/pi/MagicMirror/modules/MMM-MysqlQuery/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:118:18)
at Class.socketNotificationReceived (/home/pi/MagicMirror/modules/MMM-MysqlQuery/node_helper.js:25:17)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/pi/MagicMirror/modules/node_modules/node_helper/index.js:113:11)
at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:214:7)
at /home/pi/MagicMirror/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js:513:12
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
code: 'ENOTFOUND',
errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
hostname: 'http://192.168.8.100',
host: 'http://192.168.8.100',
port: 80,
fatal: true }
```

please let me know if the code is not enough. and thank you guys for any help I can get.

Answer (score 0):

`http://192.168.8.100` isn't a valid hostname, because it isn't a hostname at all -- it's a URL, and includes the scheme `http://`, which also isn't appropriate for a database connection.

Use simply `host: "192.168.8.100"`.

The next error you will encounter is a side effect of `port: 80` also being incorrect.  Port 80 is the standard port for an HTTP (web) server... but you are connecting to a database, not a web server.  For MySQL, the correct value would be `port: 3306` unless your MySQL installation uses a custom port (which it shouldn't).